# Running a command on Linux/Docker Cluster

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run a repo from github, namely [this](https://github.com/soroushmehr/sampleRNN_ICLR2017), on a docker cluster and I need to run this  command:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python -u ...
```

but I get this error each time:

```
stdbuf: failed to run command 'THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32': No such file or directory
```

I'm relatively new to Linux and couldn't solve it. When I run on my computer I don't get any problem.

I have a docker with python 2.7 and theano 0.8 as suggested

Answer (score 0):

This is because this is not a command. Have you got any doc ?

Comment: full verison of the command is like this: `THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python -u models/two_tier/two_tier.py ...` python command is working but i cant add flags? can i add it into py script

Comment: `but i cant add flags` how are you running the command? Can you post full line? Do you run it liek `docker run .... FLAGS=.... python`?

Comment: I have a different version of docker actually, RiseML. If it is still relevant i have a line: `run: THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python -u models/two_tier/two_tier.py -- ...` same as the given by the author. @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

This is not a command, this is environment setting. You can set variables before running the command.

Ie:

```
var=1 echo "$var"
```

The command to run is `python`. Get a docker with python2.

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python -u models/three_tier/three_tier.py --exp BEST_3TIER --seq_len 512 --big_frame_size 8 --frame_size 2 --emb_size 256 --skip_conn False --dim 1024 --n_rnn 1 --rnn_type GRU --q_levels 256 --q_type linear --batch_size 128 --weight_norm True --learn_h0 True --which_set MUSIC
```

The environment variables are set and exported by the shell. To run it as a oneliner with `docker` you have to first run the shell and pass relevant info to it. Also, be aware of the ENTRYPOINT of the docker image, overwrite it if needed.

```
docker run some_image sh -c 'THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python -u models/three_tier/three_tier.py --exp BEST_3TIER --seq_len 512 --big_frame_size 8 --frame_size 2 --emb_size 256 --skip_conn False --dim 1024 --n_rnn 1 --rnn_type GRU --q_levels 256 --q_type linear --batch_size 128 --weight_norm True --learn_h0 True --which_set MUSIC'
```

This first runs the shell `sh`. Then `sh` exports the variable `THEANO_FLAGS` with the value `mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32` (this whole line is the value of the variable). Then it calls `python` command (searched in `$PATH`) with the rest of the line as arguments to the `python` program.

Alternatively (and maybe cleaner) you can use `docker`s `-e` option, or even add the `ENV` into dockerfile:

```
docker run -e 'THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32' some_image python -u models/three_tier/three_tier.py --exp BEST_3TIER --seq_len 512 --big_frame_size 8 --frame_size 2 --emb_size 256 --skip_conn False --dim 1024 --n_rnn 1 --rnn_type GRU --q_levels 256 --q_type linear --batch_size 128 --weight_norm True --learn_h0 True --which_set MUSIC
```